Uniqueness of the octahedral axiom
The octahedral axiom for a triangulated category says that if I have two morphisms $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to C$, then there is an exact triangle $Cf \to C(g \circ f) \to C(g)$ between the cones on $f, g \circ f$, and $f$. This exact triangle sits inside of a large commutative diagram obtained by extending $f$, $g$, and $g \circ f$ to exact triangles.
How unique are the morphisms in the exact triangle $Cf \to C(g \circ f) \to Cg$? I am getting stuck working with some of the details of triangulated categories.
